# Building Client/Server Windows Based Application By C#

Tags: c#, client-server, desktop-application

I have a desktop application and i want to convert it into client-server where many users can insert, delete and update simultaneously,

I have made project in the C# .Net, so what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

This is a great tutorial: With it I've written numerous Client-Server apps.

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/sampleprograms/print.php/c7695/

Answer (score -1):

First migrate your database to something like SQL Server. To manage simultaneous updates use a version column in the tables to detect updates by other uses and take appropriate actions. Or else use the database table locking mechanism to manage simultaneous updates

Comment: Terrible idea - this will require giving every client direct access to the database. Instead, you want a server application that accesses the database and controls what users can and can't do.

Comment: Well the way his question was phrased I did't feel he has the expertise to go to the full blown server based app hence my suggestion.